# How to create a LiveSwitch.TextControl.Editor object? - C #

Tags: c#, winforms

I study the project "A Windows Forms based text with HTML output" - [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15559/A-Windows-Forms-based-text--with-HTML-output)

In this project there is an object "LiveSwitch.TextControl.Editor".

How such object is created?
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3CJN.jpg)

Comment: Well, given what's in the picture, it looks like a User Control that includes a WebBrowser control, a ToolStrip with some command buttons that are probably used to give access to some of the webBrowser document ExecCommand. It also probably uses the Microsoft Internet Controls (SHDocVw) or MSHTML or both to help with more advanced procedure (having direct access to the Interfaces (IHTMLDocument2 - IHTMLDocument6 etc.) and the Activex Object (Internet Explorer). There are also a couple of menus.

Comment: The whole article is about creating such control. Read it.